# Вложить тег в тег в JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Есть классическое меню созданный с тегами

и . В этот меню я добавил тег div. Теперь Хочу тег  вложить в созданный тег . У меня это получилось, только через цикл не получается его реализовать, т.к. там около 5 тегов . [image: Наверно тут будет понятно вложение тега в]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PYgK.jpg): [image: Это как я использую цикл, который не работает]

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cWA7.jpg): [image: Этот код как раз так и работает. Только в одном теге]

Comment: вы сами поняли что написали?

Comment: Может не смог донести мысль, русский язык у меня не родной поэтому. Короче говоря я тег <ul> хочу вложить в тег <div>. код который написано в третьем картинке, она работает, только его надо использовать с помощью цикла.

Answer (score 0):

А цикл то зачем? если я правильно понял вопрос. То вот

```html
<div class="d"></div>
<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

```js
const div = document.querySelector('.d')
const ul = document.querySelector('.list')
div.append(ul)
```